# Show that an integral does not exists

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

Consider the following integral : 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Big | \frac{e^{i(\omega+\omega_0)\frac{N\pi}{\omega_0}}e^{i\omega t}}{\omega+\omega_0}\Big |d\omega$$

I have to show that this integral does not exists. My attempt : 
I have 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Big | \frac{e^{i(\omega+\omega_0)\frac{N\pi}{\omega_0}}e^{i\omega t}}{\omega+\omega_0}\Big |d\omega=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\mid \omega+\omega_0\mid}d\omega\geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\mid \omega\mid}d\omega$$
But then, I don't really know what to do with the last integral. Can I split it ? Like this :
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\mid \omega\mid}d\omega=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ \omega}d\omega-\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{1}{ \omega}d\omega$$
Before splitting an integral, don't we have to show that it exists ? Here I am not sure if $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}1/(\mid \omega \mid)d\omega$ exists... Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

For complex $\omega_0$, it can be not trivial to get $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\mid \omega+\omega_0\mid}d\omega\geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\mid \omega\mid}d\omega$ directly.

However, you can definitely say $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\mid \omega+\omega_0\mid}d\omega\geq \int_{2|\omega_0|}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\mid \omega\mid}d\omega$ (we reduce integration area, and function is non-negative), then say  $\int_{2|\omega_0|}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\mid \omega\mid}d\omega \geqslant \int_{2|\omega_0|}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2\omega}d\omega$ (replace function with strictly lower), and the last integral obviously diverges (we can explicitly find it).

In general, if your function is non-negative (or non-positive), you can split the integral - the original integral converges iff all parts converges. Equally - integral converges absolutely iff all parts converges absolutely

If function changes sign, then it's possible for integral to converge but parts to diverge - for example, $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx$ converges, but $\int_{\{x: \sin(x) > 0\}} \frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx$ and $\int_{\{x: \sin(x) \leq 0\}} \frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx$ both diverge.

Comment: I don't really understand why your first inequality is not trivial ? I mean, for all complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ we have the triangle inequality $\mid z_1 +z_2 \mid \leq \mid z_1\mid + \mid z_2 \mid $ ? So the quotient is greater than $1/(\mid \omega\mid + \mid \omega_0 \mid)$ and because the modulus of a complex number is a real number which is positive we have that it is greater than $1/(\mid \omega\mid)$ ?

Comment: Because $1/(|\omega| + |\omega_0|)$ is less (or equal) than $1/|w|$, not greater. Take, for example, $\omega = \omega_0 = 1$: the former is $1 / 2$ and the later is $1$.